# Specify account credentials on a docker compose file on azure

Tags: azure, docker

I'm creating an app-service from several images following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli):

The example has the following code for the YML file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

The isue is that I have the container images on an Azure private registrer and using a file share to mount a volume and I don't find where to put the credentials for that.

When I use docker create this are the credentials I have to use that in the above example are missing:

```
   --registry-login-server XXXXXX \
    --registry-password XXXXXX   \
    --registry-username XXXXXX \
    --azure-file-volume-account-name thisisjustatest \
    --azure-file-volume-account-key XXXXXX \
    --azure-file-volume-share-name XXXXXX
```

In this [other example](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/06/27/How-to-use-Azure-Container-Registry-for-a-Multi-container-Web-App.html) some of the credentials are added on a later step using the web interface:

[image]

Which does not makes sense for my use case, since the idea is to automate the process, not adding more manual steps.

I also looked in the code from the CLI to create the app:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-create

And I don't see a parameter to send the account credentials.

**EDIT:**

This is the code I'm using now on the docker compose file:

```
2vecservice:
  image: coreintelligenceservices.azurecr.io/samples/word2vecservice
  container_name: "apibmongodb1"
  registry-login-server: coreintelligenceservices.azurecr.io
  registry-password: 6JZPjl3gx7JrIDaMT7r6y9gI/xBhFYXf
  registry-username: coreintelligenceservices
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  restart: always
```

I does create the app but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's designed by Azure, the credential for the docker registry is set inside the docker-compose file, it's set as the environment variables for the Azure Web App as your link shows. You can see the description [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#ACRSettings).

If you deploy your images in the portal with the docker-compose file, you need to manually to set the environment variables for the registry credential. But when you use the Azure CLI command `az webapp create` as you reference to, you can add the parameters `--docker-registry-server-user` and `--docker-registry-server-password`, this can set the registry credential for you at the creation time. According to the images in your docker-compose file, it will set the registry server URL automated.

One more thing you need to take care of is that all the images in the docker-compose must in the same registry. You can see the limitation [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#OneRegistry).

Comment: At which level in the docker file are these set? I mean, which is the set above those variables? can you write an example? I updated the question at the end

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez It is not the environment variables in the docker-compose file, it's set in Web App and it's a configuration for it.

Comment: But how do I créate créate the app then? it does not makes much sense that it is required to use the web interface to automate the process, I have to be able to do it using the CLI

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez Yes, you can do it all from the CLI, create app service and set the environment variables. The steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app).

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez Do you solve the problem?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez What is the situation? Does it solve your problem? Or you need more help?